# the specified server location (catalina home) folder is not valid

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, tomcat7, netbeans-8

I'm running Netbeans 8.1 on Windows 7. Netbeans was installed through the distro's repositories. I've now installed the package tomcat7-user so I can create a user instance of Tomcat which I can start or stop as required.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a little more context. At what point do you get the error? What actions are needed to reproduce the problem? Be as specific as possible.